# Get products by author id using a WC_Query in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, author

I trying to get products by post author id using a WC_Query in WooCommerce, so I tried to include **a new custom meta_key "_author"**, with the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_data_store_cpt_get_products_query', 'handling_custom_meta_query_keys', 10, 3 );
function handling_custom_meta_query_keys( $wp_query_args, $query_vars ) {
    $meta_key = '_author'; 
    if ( ! empty( $query_vars[$meta_key] ) ) {
        $wp_query_args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key'     => $meta_key,
            'value'   => esc_attr( $query_vars[$meta_key] ),
            'operator' => '==', 
        );
    }
    return $wp_query_args;
}
```

Then I tried to use it with `wc_get_products()`:

```
$product_list = wc_get_products( array('_author' => get_current_user_id()) );
```

but it return null array. Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply get products by author Id in a WC_Query using the undocumented parameter "author'" as follow:

```
$products = wc_get_products( array(
    'status'    => 'publish',
    'limit'     => -1,
    'author'    => get_current_user_id()
) );
```

You will get an array of `WC_Product` Objects

Comment: LoicTheAztec, Saving angel. Thank you alot. I put the cart before the horse.

Answer (score 2):

You can use custom query like this

```
<?php

$authorID = get_the_author_meta('ID');

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'product_cat' => 'pants'
    'author'    => $authorID
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

?>        
<div class="author_products">
    <?php if ( $loop->have_posts() ) { ?>
        <ul class="author_pubproducts">
        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php
        } else {
            echo __( 'No products found', 'textdomain' );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

Hope it's work

Comment: Thanks alot, But I wanted to get wc_get_products outputs. :)